# Guardar SharedPreferences asignandole una key mediante getDefaultSharedPreferences()

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

tengo una clase para guardar el email y usuario que se conectan en la aplicación con `sharedpreferences` , pero me guarda los datos sin ninguna `key` de referencia por lo que cuando quiero guardar un dato diferente sin sobrescribir el anterior no me lo hace , me imagino que necesitare asignarle alguna `key` para referenciarlo y poder guardar el dato que quiero sin pisar el anterior y asignándole un nombre :

```
public void save(Context context, String text) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    Editor editor;

    settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    editor = settings.edit();

    editor.putString(PREFS_KEY, text);

    editor.commit();
}
```

Aquí llamo a la función :

```
String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
sharedPreference.save(this, email);
```

Comment: Si necesitas la posibilidad de guardar varias entradas, por ejemplo direcciones de correo, lo mejor es usar una base de datos **Sqlite**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No creo que no se este guardando el valor, el problema es que se tiene que obtener de esta forma el valor guardado, (suponiendo que tu llave es `email`)

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String email = preferences.getString("email, "");
```

Recuerda que usas [getDefaultSharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)) el cual no requiere un nombre para el archivo de preferencias, pero sus valores de preferencias si.

Agrego como se realiza con los dos métodos:

#### Guardar y obtener un valor mediante [getDefaultSharedPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context))

```
public void saveValuePreference(Context context, String text) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("email", text);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getValuePreference(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return  preferences.getString("email", "");
}
```

#### Guardar y obtener un valor mediante **[getSharedPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getSharedPreferences())**

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";

public void saveValuePreference(Context context, String text) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("email", text);
    editor.commit();
}



public String getValuePreference(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getString("email", "");
}
```

Comment: cierto @Elenasys , lo he cambiado y lo he puesto asi :
       `public void save(Context context, String text) {
            SharedPreferences settings;
            Editor editor;

        
            settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,    Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
            editor = settings.edit(); 

            editor.putString(PREFS_KEY, text); 

            editor.commit(); 
        }`

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elenasys , me ha quedado mucho mas claro :)

Answer (score 4):

Tienes que usar `android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;`
Aqui te pongo un ejemplo de una clase con dos metodos que guarda shared preferences con una key:

```
public class AlmacenPuntuacionesPreferencias implements AlmacenPuntuaciones {
    private static String PREFERENCIAS="puntuaciones";
    private Context context;
    public AlmacenPuntuacionesPreferencias(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    public void guardaPuntuacion(int puntos, String nombre, long fecha) {
        SharedPreferences preferencias=context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCIAS,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferencias.edit();
        for (int n = 9; n >=1; n--) {
            editor.putString("puntuacion"+n,preferencias.getString("puntuacion"+(n-1),""));

        }
        editor.putString("puntuacion0", puntos+" "+nombre);
        editor.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public Vector<String> listaPuntuaciones(int cantidad) {
        Vector<String> result=new Vector<String>();
        SharedPreferences preferencias=context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCIAS,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        for (int n = 0; n <=9; n++) {
            String s=preferencias.getString("puntuacion"+n,"");
            if(s!=""){
                result.add(s);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Creo que esto ya puedes adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias @abrahamhs , me ha sido de mucha ayuda .

Comment: por eso puse que debía adaptarlo a sus necesidades