# Obtener datos remotos usando Loopj

Tags: java, android, json

Estoy usando loopj para logearme y registrarme usando un WebService remoto que utiliza MySQL para almacenar datos.
El WebService lo tengo configurado para que cuando un usuario se logea me de una respuesta en formato objeto "Json" tipo:

```
{
"estado": 1
"ususrio": {
  "user_name": "antonio"
  "user_email": "info@tradecall.com"
  "claveApi": "1b0f21451af767eba3cee46b18caaa74"
  }
}
```

Si la respuesta es 200 ok entonces el logeo es correcto.
Me funciona bien, pero ahora quisiera usar uno de los parámetros que devuelve el servidor, en concreto quisiera usar la **"claveApi**" para almacenarla en una constante y tratarla en otra clase dentro de la misma app. 
Agradecería si alguien me pudiera poner un ejemplo de como hacerlo.

Código de mi login:(Ps. el login está enmarcado gráficamente dentro de un drawer design)

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

//Defining views
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText textUser_pass;
private AppCompatButton btnLogin;
private AppCompatButton btnLinkToRegisterScreen;
private AppCompatButton Returning;
private CookieStore cookieStore;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

// Progress Dialog Object
ProgressDialog prgDialog;
// Error Msg TextView Object
TextView errorMsg;
// Email Edit View Object

private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://wi-sen.esy.es/wisen/Sensores/v1/usuarios/login";

//boolean variable to check user is logged in or not
//initially it is false
private boolean loggedIn = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    agregarToolbar();

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    if (navigationView != null) {
        prepararDrawer(navigationView);
        // Seleccionar item por defecto
        seleccionarItem(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));
    }

    // Find Error Msg Text View control by ID
    errorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);
    // Instantiate Progress Dialog object
    prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Set Progress Dialog Text
    prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    // Set Cancelable as False
    prgDialog.setCancelable(false);



    //Initializing views
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    textUser_pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textUser_pass);


    btnLogin = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegisterScreen = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
    Returning = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.Returning);

    //Adding click listener
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnLinkToRegisterScreen.setOnClickListener(this);
    Returning.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void agregarToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null) {
        // Poner ÃƒÂ­cono del drawer toggle
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.drawer_toggle);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}
private void prepararDrawer(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    seleccionarItem(menuItem);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                }
            });

}
private void seleccionarItem(MenuItem itemDrawer) {
    Fragment fragmentoGenerico = null;

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();




    switch (itemDrawer.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.item_web:

            startActivity(new Intent(this, com.amg_eservices.appiot.SaltoWeb.WebOficial.class));
            break;


        case R.id.item_categorias:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, com.amg_eservices.appiot.MisSensores.ui.ActividadListaObjeto.class));
            break;

        case R.id.item_acceso:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, com.amg_eservices.appiot.RegistroyAcceso.MainActivity.class));
            break;
    }
    if (fragmentoGenerico != null) {
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.contenido_principal, fragmentoGenerico)
                .commit();


    }

    // Setear titulo actual
    setTitle(itemDrawer.getTitle());
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //In onresume fetching value from sharedpreference
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //Fetching the boolean value form sharedpreferences
    loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Calling the login function
    if (v == btnLogin) {
        login(v);
    }
    if (v == btnLinkToRegisterScreen) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
    if (v == Returning) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, com.amg_eservices.appiot.MainActivity.class));
    }


}


private void login(View v) {
    //Getting values from edit texts
    //final String txt_umail = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    //final String txt_upass = textUser_pass.getText().toString().trim();

    final String user_email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String contrasena = textUser_pass.getText().toString().trim();

    // Instantiate Progress Dialog object
    prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Set Progress Dialog Text
    prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    // Set Cancelable as False
    prgDialog.setCancelable(false);

    //Creating a shared preference
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = Login.this.getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    //Adding values to editor
    editor.putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
    //editor.putString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, user_mail);
    editor.putString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, user_email);

    //Saving values to editor
    editor.commit();

    LoginLoopj(user_email, contrasena);

}

//LoginLoopj(user_email, contrasena);
// TODO: 09/05/16 make the http call loopj here

private void LoginLoopj(String user_email, String contrasena) {

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();
    StringEntity entity = null;
    try {
        jsonParams.put(UtilitiesGlobal.USER_EMAIL, user_email);
        // Put Http parameter password with value of Password Edit View control
        jsonParams.put(UtilitiesGlobal.USER_PASSWORD, contrasena);

        entity = new StringEntity(jsonParams.toString());
        entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // When Name Edit View, Email Edit View and Password Edit View have values other than Null

    if (Utility.isNotNull(user_email) && Utility.isNotNull(contrasena)) {
        if (Utility.validate(user_email)) {
            // Put Http parameter name with value of Name Edit View control

            LoginLoopj(user_email, contrasena);
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter valid email or blank spaces", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // client.post(REGISTER_URL, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    // Invoke RESTful Web Service with Http parameters
    RequestHandle post = client.post(this, LOGIN_URL, entity, "application/json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            // called before request is started
        }

        @Override

        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
            String responseStr = null;
            try {



                responseStr = new String(response, "UTF-8");


            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i(UtilitiesGlobal.TAG, "onSuccess: loopj " + responseStr);

            Toast toast1 =
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.string.Logeo_exitoso, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            toast1.show();



            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, ProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override

        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
            // Hide Progress Dialog
            prgDialog.hide();
            // When Http response code is '404'
            if (statusCode == 404) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // When Http response code is '500'
            else if (statusCode == 500) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // When Http response code other than 404, 500
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    });


}
public void navigatetoLoginActivity(View view) {
    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
    // Clears History of Activity
    loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(loginIntent);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_actividad_principal, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

---

Hasta aquí era el archivo sin modificar.
Ahora he cambiado la parte de `onSuccess` como sigue:

```
 public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
            String responseStr = null;
            JSONObject jsonobject = null;

            try {


                responseStr = new String(response, "UTF-8");


                jsonobject = new JSONObject(responseStr);
                String claveApi = jsonobject.getString("claveApi");
                Log.i(UtilitiesGlobal.TAG, "onSuccess: loopj " + jsonobject + claveApi);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Toast toast1 =
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.string.Logeo_exitoso, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            toast1.show();


            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, ProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Y el error que sale en el log es que la claveApi no tiene valores, es como si no reconociera la respuesta del servidor, antes en el log si que me decía que tenía los datos de "estado, user_name, user_email y claveApi":
Log

**Un Objeto dentro de otro objeto**

Esta modificación da el siguiente error.

Código:

```
  public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
            JSONObject jsonobject = null;
            String claveApi = "";


            try {
                jsonobject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                JSONObject usuarioiJSONbject = jsonobject.getJSONObject("usuario");
                claveApi = usuarioiJSONbject.getString("claveApi");

                Log.i(UtilitiesGlobal.TAG, "onSuccess: loopj " + jsonobject + claveApi);

            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, ProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

**LOG**

```
06-06 22:30:09.973 4709-4709/? W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 11 of [B@3dc20986
06-06 22:30:09.977 4709-4709/? W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
06-06 22:30:09.977 4709-4709/? W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.readArray(JSONTokener.java:440)
06-06 22:30:09.978 4709-4709/? W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:103)
06-06 22:30:09.978 4709-4709/? W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
06-06 22:30:09.978 4709-4709/? W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
06-06 22:30:09.990 4709-4709/? W/System.err:     at com.amg_eservices.appiot.RegistroyAcceso.Login$2.onSuccess(Login.java:308)
```

Comment: agregué una actualización en tu caso tienes un objeto y dentro el objeto ususrio ( yo lo manejé en mi respuesta como "usuario"), por esa razón se tiene que obtener el objecto dentro de un objeto y después el valor, saludos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creo que tu pregunta va desde el parseo del dato, guardado y reutilizarlo en una clase:

Ok, la respuesta .Json puede ser de dos tipos:

- Si el .json inicia con { se considera como objeto Json.
- Si el .json inicia con [ es considerado como Arreglo Json.

En tu caso al parecer es un objeto, entonces para obtener el valor del API Key:

```
        JSONObject jsonobject = null;
        try {
            jsonobject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            String claveApi = jsonobject.getString("claveApi");
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Ahora puedes guardar el valor en preferencias, te recomiendo este **[link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8564/95)** en donde se encuentran métodos para agregar y obtener los valores de una preferencia, para obtener los valores del API Key simplemente usa el método `getValuePreference()` .

**Actualización:**

#### Obtener el valor dentro de un objecto que a su vez esta dentro de otro:

Si revisamos detenidamente el objecto nos podemos dar cuenta que claveApi esta en realidad dentro de otro objeto `usuario`

```
{
"estado": 1
"usuario": {
            "user_name": "antonio"
            "user_email": "info@tradecall.com"
            "claveApi": "1b0f21451af767eba3cee46b18caaa74"
          }
}
```

En este caso primero obtenemos el objeto principal, después obtenemos el objeto `usuario` y al final obtenemos el valor de `claveApi`:

```
    JSONObject jsonobject = null;
    String claveApi = "";
    try {
        jsonobject = new JSONObject(jsonString);            
        JSONObject usuarioiJSONbject = jsonobject.getJSONObject("usuario");
        claveApi = usuarioiJSONbject.getString("claveApi");
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

con esto podrás obtener sin problema el valor de `claveApi` : `1b0f21451af767eba3cee46b18caaa74`

Comment: Hola Elenasys. Mucgas gracias por la respuesta. Entriendo que el código quedaría así: `try {
                    responseStr = new String(response, "UTF-8");
                    JSONObject jsonobject;
                    jsonobject = new JSONObject(responseStr);
                    JSONObject jornada;
                    String claveApi = jornada.getString("claveApi");

               Pero no entiendo muy bien que es "jornada"

Comment: perdon @oscarc debe ser el objeto, ya edite la respuesta, saludos.

Comment: Y si, te forza a agregar a agregar un manejo de exception,JSONException!

Comment: Hola Elenasys.¿Como quedaría el código completo dentro de "public void onSuccess(....). Lo estoy probando de varias formas pero el log me dice que Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference. cuando incluyo tu recomendación. Gracias por anticipado.

Comment: @oscarc trato de ver donde se provocaría el error dentro de onSuccess(), si modificaste el método agregalo a tu pregunta! en el LogCat debe mostrarte en que método se esta provocando el error.

Comment: Hola Elenasys. EN mi pregunta, al final, he añadido la parte que he modificado del código, "OnSuccess" y el log con el mensaje de error, (No value for claveApi). Es como si no reconociera el objeto. Si te fijas, antes de modificar, en la respuesta que obtenía, era un Object , no un array, y su nómbre era "usuario"

Comment: Oscar, revisa ahí que responseStr en verdad sea un .json y  dentro tenga el key de "claveApi".

Comment: Hola Elenasys- Pues ya he probado todo, y sigue diciéndo que los valores están vacios.

Comment: Hola Elenasys- Pues ya he probado todo, y sigue diciéndo que los valores están vacios. En el log dice que hay datos en la respuesta "onSuccess: loopj {"estado":1,"ususrio":{"user_name":"oscar cuenca","user_email":"oscarcuenca2@hotmail.com","claveApi":"a3140b7a8f6bb6f3475e6fec743e4dcd"}}, esto quiere decir que en "response" están estos datos, que tienen estructura de JsonObject. En OnSuccess he llamado a `"JsonObject response"` y  en el client `"new JsonHttpResponseHandler()"` para que de forma automática lo combierta en un JsonObject, cuando intento pasar estos datos a una MAP no lo pasa.

Comment: Hola ELenasys. Si es cierto, es un objeto dentro de otro, me he fijado el los breakets. Implementando tu solución da un error de: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 11 of [B@3dc20986     en la línea 308. He puesto al final de mi pregunta el log con el error y he pegado el código con tu última solución.  Es como si no pudiera seguir leyendo una vez que ha empezado, ya me había salido anteriormente con otra prueba este mismo error y no seguí indagando sobre él.

Comment: El "jsonstring" que se supone que es el response recibido, el editor me obliga a poner "(String.valueOf(response))" ya que si pongo "response"me da un aviso de "wrap using stringvalueOf  y por se motivo debo poner "(String.valueOf(response))". Es la única variación que he hecho sobre tu propuesta.

Comment: imprime el json que se recibe con eso puedes ver cual es el problema, tal vez algún caracter al final como un ",".

Comment: Hola Elenasys. Tienes razón, es un error de sintaxis, he revisado la respuesta en http://json.parser.online.fr/ y me da error. Los errores son básicamente que le faltan las comas inferiores de separación a los atributos del objeto. Desde mi WebService en PHP envía así la información. Por tanto ahora tengo que configurar correctamente el PHP del servidor, voy a ver si puedo encontrar ayuda en PHP. Muchas gracías.

Comment: Ok entonces ese es el problema, debes asegurar se envíen correctamente los datos en una estructura .json, para que el JSONParser funcione adecuadamente, Saludos!

Comment: He estado a punto de modificar mi PHP WebSerivce, pero algo por dentro me estaba diciendo que ese no era el camino. Tengo servicios que usan el WebService sin problemas, especialmente la parte autentificación. Si lo modifico  me falllará otros servicios asociados, pues el PHP está comprobado correctamente con un servicio web REST. Por tanto he probado en cambiar el response a "JsonHttpResponseHandler()" y el OnSuccess a JSonObject response y onFailure a JsonArray response y de esta forma loopj se ocupa de formatear correctamente el Objeto que viene del servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Según la respuesta de Elenasys. He probado su respuesta y ha funcionado correctamente. Al recibir un Objeto Json del servidor el código quedaría así:

```
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
                String responseStr = null;
                try {
                    JSONObject jornada;
                    jornada = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                    String claveApi = jornada.getString("claveApi");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Ahora voy a trabajar sobre sharepreferences para manipular el dato en cuestión.

Comment: Hola Elenasys. No pensé que al marcar también otra respuesta se desmarcará la tuya. Te pido perdón. Ya la he vuelto a marcar, creo. Llevo poc tiempo usando activamente stackoverflow, ese es el motivo de mi error. Sorry...