# Guardar opciones seleccionadas en SharePreferences de un AlertDialog Multichoice

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, alertdialog, multichoice

Buenas tardes

Tengo un AlertDialog en el actionbar Multichoice, el cual lleno desde un webservices.

Necesito que cuando el usuario selecciones una o x opciones y le de click en ok, se guarde esas opciones seleccionas en las Sharepreferences del sistema, para cuando se vuelva a generar el dialogo me guarde las opciones seleccionadas.

Les dejo código donde creo mi Alertdialog

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList){
        super.onPostExecute(arrayList);

        final String[] zona = new String[ZonaArrayList.size()];
        // zona = ZonaArrayList.toArray(zona);
        for(int i=0; i<ZonaArrayList.size(); i++){
            //Obtiene el campo Descripción y lo agrega al array de strings "zona".
            zona[i] = ZonaArrayList.get(i).getDescripcion();
            // zona[i] = ZonaArrayList.get(i).getClave();
            //
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(Clientes.this);


        dialog.setTitle("Selecciona la(s) Zonas a Visitar");
        final boolean[] selZona={false,false,false};
        dialog.setMultiChoiceItems(zona,selZona,new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(arg2) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Zona Seleccionada " + zona[arg1],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //Mandar a llamar metodo Clientes con el filtro
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
                AsynClien task = new AsynClien(settings.getString("ONControlWSURL", "").toString());
                //Call execute
                task.execute();
            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog=dialog.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Revisa las respuestas de este [post](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559/guardar-sharedpreferences-asignandole-una-key/)

Comment: @HugoRodriguez preguntaba si lo que deseabas era guardar los estados de los check y siempre actualizarlos para agregar una respuesta. Me refiero que de acuerdo a el elemento guarde su propio estado.

Comment: si mira me refieron a que como tu sabras ese alertdialog yo lo lleno con un array de objecto del cual yo obtengo la descripcion, y lo que yo queria es que cuando el usuario seleccione una opciones yo guardar el id del objeto en mis preferencias pero yo poder accederlo desde otro lado

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes vamos a ello, lo primero inicializamos SharedPreferences:

```
  SharedPreferences  sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
  SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPrefeditor= sharedPref.edit();
```

Guardar selección:

```
 dialog.setMultiChoiceItems(zona,selZona,new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           selZona[arg1] = !selZona[arg1]; 
        }
    });   


  dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               sharedPrefeditor.putBoolean("opcion_1",  selZona[0]); 
               sharedPrefeditor.putBoolean("opcion_2",  selZona[1]);
               sharedPrefeditor.putBoolean("opcion_3",  selZona[2]);
               sharedPrefeditor.commit();
            }
        });
```

Iniciamos `selZona` con los datos seleccionados:

```
  final boolean[] selZona={false,false,false};
  selZona[0] = sharedPref.getBoolean("opcion_1",  false);
  selZona[1] = sharedPref.getBoolean("opcion_2",  false);
  selZona[2] = sharedPref.getBoolean("opcion_3",  false);
```

Si ves que con esto último no salen seleccionados puedes probar esto:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < selZona.length; i++) {
     ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(i,  selZona[i]);
 }
```

Un saludo

Comment: ok deja probar, ahorita te digo que onda

Comment: amigo solo que yo lo que necesito guardar en las preferencia, mira deja te expico, ese alertdialog yo lo lleno con un array de objetos, entonces yo lo que necesito guardar cuando selecciones es el id del objeto guardado

Comment: si me sirve este ejemplo que me pones para que me mantenga seleccionado los check

Comment: Te refieres a ZonaArrayList?

Comment: Aunque realmente esta pregunta creo que ya está resuelta, no te recomiendo Sharedprefrences para guardas ids de objetos, si quieres puedes formular otra pregunta de como guardar las ids y te pongo ejemplos

Comment: asi es ok, deja genero otra pregunta...

Comment: Elenasys no puedo ver tu comentario, lo puedes vovler a poner?

Comment: Por favor marca esta respuesta  si está ok ;) un saludo