# Almacenar fecha con la que se inicie una app

Tags: android-studio, date, sharedpreferences

Hay alguna forma de almacenar una fecha ingresada (al iniciar la app) y que
con esa fecha almacenada, cada vez que inice la app no sea necesario volverla
a ingresar. Al ingresar esa fecha, por medio de Calendar realiza operaciones 
(agrega y quita dias) ademas de que a diario realiza conteo de días que faltan para que se llegue a la fecha ingresada. Lo intenté con SharedPreferences pero no me guarda nada.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.en_salud.vencimiento.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Ingrese Fecha de Vencimiento"
            android:id="@+id/txtIngrese"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/btnSelecFecha"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:hint="seleccione la fecha"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:background="#afafaf"
            android:textColorHint="#fc0105"
            android:textStyle="italic" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/txtDiasFaltan"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/txtFechaVencimiento"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDiasFaltan"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/txtFecha7menos"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtFechaVencimiento"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/txtFecha30mas"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtFecha7menos"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="GUARDAR"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/btnGuardar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/btn3"
        android:id="@id/btnReiniciar"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView txtDiasFaltan,txtIngrese,txtFechaVencimiento,txtFecha7menos,
            txtFecha30mas,btnSelecFecha,btnReiniciar;
    Button btnGuardar;
    SharedPreferences sf;
    public static final String preference = "pref";
    public static final String saveIt = "saveKey";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtDiasFaltan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDiasFaltan);
        txtIngrese = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtIngrese);
        txtFechaVencimiento = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFechaVencimiento);
        txtFecha7menos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFecha7menos);
        txtFecha30mas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFecha30mas);
        btnSelecFecha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnSelecFecha);
        btnReiniciar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnReiniciar);
        btnGuardar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGuardar);
        sf = getSharedPreferences(preference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (sf.contains(saveIt)){
            txtDiasFaltan.setText(sf.getString(saveIt,""));
        }

        btnSelecFecha.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnGuardar.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnReiniciar.setOnClickListener(this);
        txtDiasFaltan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        readSharedPreferences();

    }

    private void createSharedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sf.edit();
        String dias = txtDiasFaltan.getText().toString();
        editor.putString(saveIt, dias);
        editor.commit();

    }

    private void readSharedPreferences() {
        sf =getSharedPreferences(preference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        txtDiasFaltan = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtDiasFaltan);
        if (sf.contains(saveIt)){
            txtDiasFaltan.setText(sf.getString(saveIt,""));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.btnSelecFecha:
                DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
                picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
                break;

            case R.id.btnReiniciar:
                super.recreate();
                break;

            case R.id.btnGuardar:
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("GUARDAR FECHA");
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Confirma la fecha")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Si",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                //btnReiniciar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                btnGuardar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                //onPause();
                                createSharedPreferences ();
                                readSharedPreferences ();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("CANCELAR",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
}


    public class DatePickerFragment extends android.app.DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        return  dpd;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
        TextView txtDiasFaltan = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtDiasFaltan);
        TextView txtFechaVencimiento = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtFechaVencimiento);
        TextView txtFecha7menos = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtFecha7menos);
        TextView txtFecha30mas = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtFecha30mas);


        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EE  dd/MM/yyyy");
        long date1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);

        long Date2 = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        txtFechaVencimiento.setText("Vence el día:         " + df.format(cal.getTime()));

        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
        txtFecha7menos.setText("7 días previos:       " + df.format(cal.getTime()));

        cal.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);
        txtFecha30mas.setText("30 días despues:     " + df.format(cal.getTime()));


            long diffInMilis = Date2 - date1;
            long diffInDays = diffInMilis / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            //long diffInWeeks = diffInMilis / (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

            txtDiasFaltan.setText("faltan "+ diffInDays + " días");

        textViewVisible();

    }
    private void textViewVisible() {
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtIngrese).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnSelecFecha).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtDiasFaltan).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtFechaVencimiento).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtFecha7menos).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtFecha30mas).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnGuardar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnReiniciar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Armen, no te guarda nada ya que no estas definiendo cual es el nombre de la preferencia, cuando se usa [getSharedPreferences()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)) al momento de guardar y obtener la preferencia debe ser mediante el nombre de la misma, esta seria la correccion:

```
private void createSharedPreferences() {
    sf = getSharedPreferences(preference, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sf.edit();
    String dias = txtDiasFaltan.getText().toString();
    editor.putString(saveIt, dias);
    editor.commit();
}
```

mas informacion : **[Guardar y obtener un valor mediante getSharedPreferences()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8564/95)**

#### Actualización:

He revisado tu código y en una preferencia no puedes buscar el "key" mediante el método `contains()` puesto que no es un String, tu validación no permitia accedieras al valor en la preferencia.

```
private void readSharedPreferences() {
        sf =getSharedPreferences(preference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        txtDiasFaltan = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtDiasFaltan);
        //if(sf.contains(saveIt)){
            txtDiasFaltan.setText(sf.getString(saveIt,""));
        //}

    }
```

Si deseas la validación puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
 if(sf.getString(saveIt,"") != null && !sf.getString(saveIt,"").isEmpty()){
       txtDiasFaltan.setText(sf.getString(saveIt,""));
 }
```

Comment: Gracias Elenasys. sf ya esta declarado en `onCreate`, de todas maneras hize las modificaciones como dices y nada. No entiendo porque. También lo intenté con `onSaveIntanceState` y tampoco (incluso con clean, rebuild y reiniciando Android Studio. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: armen, he revisando tu código y he encontrado el problema, ve mi actualización, si estabas guardando seguramente el valor pero cuando realizabas esta sentencia if(sf.contains(saveIt)){ , nunca iba a permitir buscar el valor en la preferencia.