# ¿Cómo obtener un valor de un ArrayList que fue guardado con SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

¿me podrían ayudar porfavor? Estoy desarrollando un aplicación en Android, cuenta con 2 activitys *MainActivity* y *SegundaActivity*.
 En el *MainActivity* hay un TextView que quiero que muestre un elemento del ArrayList que tengo en el *SegundaActivity* al presionar un botón.

No puedo encontrar la manera. Me gustaría saber como ya que no entiendo completamente el código pues algunas partes las adapte de otro código...

Este es el primer activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button botonOtraActividad, botonRespuesta;
private TextView mostrarRespuesta;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mostrarRespuesta = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    botonOtraActividad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    botonRespuesta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);


    // Con esto se abre el Segundo Activity
    botonOtraActividad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, SegundaActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } });
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->>


    botonRespuesta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences prefe1 = getSharedPreferences("datosrespuestas", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            mostrarRespuesta.setText( ); // Aqui es donde debe de ir lo que me hace falta almenos eso creo

        } });
    }
}
```

y este es el segundo activity

```
public class SegundaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<String> respuestas;   
private ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador1; 
private ListView lv1;
private EditText et1;
private SharedPreferences prefe1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_segunda);

    respuestas = new ArrayList<String>();
    respuestas.add("respuesta1"); 
    respuestas.add("respuesta2");
    respuestas.add("respuesta3");

    leerSharedPreferences();


    adaptador1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,respuestas);
    lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv1.setAdapter(adaptador1);
    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    lv1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            final int posicion = i;

            AlertDialog.Builder dialogo1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(SegundaActivity.this);
            dialogo1.setTitle("Importante");
            dialogo1.setMessage("¿ Eliminar esta Respuesta ?");
            dialogo1.setCancelable(false);
            dialogo1.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                    String s=respuestas.get(posicion);
                    StringTokenizer tok1=new StringTokenizer(s,":");
                    String nom=tok1.nextToken().trim();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor elemento=prefe1.edit();
                    elemento.remove(nom);
                    elemento.commit();

                    respuestas.remove(posicion);
                    adaptador1.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });
            dialogo1.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                }
            });
            dialogo1.show();

            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void leerSharedPreferences() {
    prefe1=getSharedPreferences("datosrespuestas", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Map<String,?> claves = prefe1.getAll();
    for(Map.Entry<String,?> ele : claves.entrySet()) {
        respuestas.add(ele.getKey()  + ele.getValue().toString());
    }
}
public void agregar(View v) {

    respuestas.add(et1.getText().toString());
    adaptador1.notifyDataSetChanged();  
    SharedPreferences.Editor elemento=prefe1.edit();
    elemento.putString(et1.getText().toString(),"");
    elemento.commit();
    et1.setText("");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la librería `Gson` para guardar el arraylist lo pasas a `json` y se guarda como `String` en el `SharedPreference` y al recuperarlo pues conviertes el `json` a lista.

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**Para guardar**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(lista);
prefsEditor.putString("key_value", jsonStr);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

**para recuperar**

```
String jsonStr = Prefs.getString("key_value", null);
String[] lista = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, String[].class);
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente al agregar tu valor a la preferencia debe tener un identificador y un valor por ejemplo:

```
editor.putString("miidentificador", "mivalor");
```

Entonces tienes que realizar una modificación al agregar el valor

```
public void agregar(View v) {
    respuestas.add(et1.getText().toString());
    adaptador1.notifyDataSetChanged();  
    SharedPreferences.Editor elemento = prefe1.edit();
    //elemento.putString(et1.getText().toString(),"");
    //Guardaras un valor con el identificador "mivalor".
    elemento.putString("mivalor",et1.getText().toString());
    elemento.commit();
    et1.setText("");
 }
```

De esta forma al guardarlo lo podrías obtener con el mismo identificador

```
  botonRespuesta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences prefe1 = getSharedPreferences("datosrespuestas", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            obtiene el valor de la preferencia con el identificador "mivalor".
            String valor = preferences.getString("mivalor", "");
            mostrarRespuesta.setText(valor); 

        } });
    }
```

Te recomiendo veas **[esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8564/95)**  donde puedes ver como se realiza el guardado y recuperación de datos mediante `getSharedPreferences()`.