# ¿Cómo guardar contraseña en una variable?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy realizando una app en Android Studio y quisiera incluir una pantalla de bloqueo para el contenido de la app pero quisiera que la contraseña la introduzca el usuario, ¿se necesita una base de datos para esto? ya que quiero que la contraseña se guarde de manera local (talvez una variable) y así el usuario pueda cambiarla cuando quiera, espero su consejo, gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Esta comunidad es un poco diferente a un foro. Verás, no es el mejor sitio para solicitar opiniones o consejos, sino para buscar respuestas a preguntas puntuales sobre programación y elegir la respuesta que solucione ese problema y ya que pides consejo cualquiera es bueno... por ejemplo, yo te aconsejo que visites [la presentación de la comunidad](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas como funciona y que uses Google para tu investigación.

Comment: Puedes usar una base de datos para esto o puedes usar shared preferences: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8564/95

Comment: @toledano al contrario, este es el mejor sitio. Esta es una pregunta concreta y no se basa en opiniones. Creo que el trabajo con contraseñas no es novedad en este campo y no es que existas múltiples maneras de almacenar contraseñas actualmente, es más existe algo conocido como mejores prácticas para este tema.

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes hacer de manera simple con el objeto [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) (documentación en inglés), te dejo un simple ejemplo:

**Configuración de los valores en** `SharedPreferences`**:**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

editor.putString("PASSWORD", "MY_PASSWORD");
editor.commit();
```

**Obteniendo los valores de** `SharedPreferences`**:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String password = prefs.getString("PASSWORD", null);
if (password != null) {
    // Tu contraseña está disponible para usarse como String
}
```