# Guardar imágenes en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, android-imageview

quería saber como puedo hacer para guardar una imagen.

Mi app tiene 2 botones y según el botón que se presione el image view recibe una imagen. Lo que quiero hacer es que se guarde esa imagen y que al volver a entrar quede la imagen elegida.

La única forma que se para guardar cosas es shared preferences pero en este caso no esta funcionando.

Alguien me puede decir que me esta faltando? Gracias.

Este es el código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView imagen;
Button boton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen);
    boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton);

    SharedPreferences preferences= getSharedPreferences("Preferencias", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String imagen= preferences.getString("Imagen", null);
}

public void boton1(View view){

    imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen1);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("Imagen", imagen.getResources().toString());
    editor.apply();
}

public void boton2(View view){

    imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen2);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("Imagen", imagen.getResources().toString());
    editor.apply();
}
```

}

Comment: Recibes algun error? Que es exactamente lo que guardas en las preferences? Puedes poner el valor de ese src?

Answer (score 2):

Antes de responder la pregunta **quiero comentar que no es posible guardar los bytes de una imagen en SharedPreferences**, lo que se guarda regularmente es el url o el path de la imagen en un tipo String.

Ejemplo:

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor edit = pref.edit();
    edit.putString("ruta_imagen","/sdcard/myImagen.jpg");
    edit.commit();
```

En tu código usa el método **[commit()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit())** para actualizar el valor de la preferencia.

---

Para que funcione asegura que `imagen.getResources().toString()` en verdad contenga un valor tipo `String` :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("Imagen", imagen.getResources().toString());
    editor.commit();
```

---

Mas información: [Uso de SharedPreferences y DefaultSharedPreferences](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8564/95).

Answer (score 1):

Sólo debes cambiar

```
editor.apply();
```

por

```
editor.commit();
```