# Como selecciono una tab de un TabLayout?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Estoy utilizando un ViewPager, pero probé intentando seleccionarlo y no pude hacerlo correctamente. Por defecto me selecciona la primera tab pero necesito que la tab seleccionada por defecto sea la segunda.

Además, cuando ingreso a otra actividad y luego presiono back vuelve a la tab por defecto.¿ Existe alguna forma de guardar la tab seleccionada cuando voy hacia la otra actividad y que cuando regrese pueda seleccionar la tab que guardé previamente?

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código que intentaste hasta ahora, por más que esté incompleto o no funcione? Pensemos en facilitar la tarea de alguien que quiera ayudarte, si no tiene un fragmento de código sobre el cual basar su respuesta, debería escribir todo el código de cero. En cambio, con un ejemplo de tu parte, sólo debería editar las partes relevantes, incluso utilizando los mismos nombres de objetos que en tu código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no usas un *ViewPager*, puedes seleccionar un tab con

```
// seleccionar primer tab
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();

// cambiar a quinto tab
tabLayout.getTabAt(4).select();
```

Comment: Estoy utilizando un ViewPager, pero probé con tu código y funciona, el caso es que cuando ingreso a otra actividad y luego presiono back vuelve a la tab por defecto. Existe alguna forma de guardar la tab seleccionada cuando voy hacia la otra actividad y que cuando regrese pueda seleccionar la tab que guarde previamente?

Comment: Podrías guardar el indice del tab en _SharedPreferences_ y recrear el estado en _onStart(...)_ de tu Activity.

Comment: Muchas gracias! chicos ya lo conseguí.

Comment: Entonces devuelve algo a la comunidad y comparte tu código que usaste para solucionar el tema. ;)

Comment: @JuanBaquedano esto creo que puede solucionar lo que deseas, simplemente guarda en preferencias el indice del último tab, http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8564/95