# Mi app crashea cuando añado un ImageView a un fragment o CardView

Tags: android, android-fragment, nullpointerexception, android-imageview, android-recyclerview

Estoy intentando hacer un CardView como los de Twitter para usarlos en un RecyclerView que se encuentra dentro de un fragment.

El CardView funciona perfectamente, pero cuando añado algún ImageView me salta un NullPointerException al obtener los datos de un EditText de un método de la actividad anterior (el encargado de pasar al activity de los fragments)

Este es el **código** del CardView sin el ImageView (**No da error**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/twoot_cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/twootUserImg"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/user_round" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/twootContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/twootUserImg"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/twootUserImg">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/twootUserName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="UserName"
                    android:textColor="#404040"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/twootUserTwoot"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="This is a sample Twoot" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/twootUserRetwoot"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="8" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/twootUserLike"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="15" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Este es el **código** del CardView con los ImageView (**No funciona**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/twoot_cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/twootUserImg"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/user_round" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/twootContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/twootUserImg"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/twootUserImg">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/twootUserName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/username"
                    android:textColor="#404040"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/twootUserTwoot"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="This is a sample Twoot" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/retwoot" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/twootUserRetwoot"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="8" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/heart" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/twootUserLike"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="15" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Este es el **error** que recibo:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.twittor, PID: 13755
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.twittor.LoginActivity.Next(LoginActivity.java:32)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

**Información extra:**

Método Next():

```
public void Next(View view){
        String usermail = userMail.getText().toString();
        String userpass = userPass.getText().toString();

        if(!usermail.isEmpty()&&!userpass.isEmpty()){
            AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "twittor", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor fila = BaseDeDatos.rawQuery("select username, mail, password from usuarios where (mail='"+usermail+"')", null);
            if(fila.moveToFirst()){
                if(fila.getString(2).equals(userpass)) {
                    Intent principal = new Intent(this, PrincipalActivity.class);
                    principal.putExtra("userName", fila.getString(0));
                    principal.putExtra("userMail", fila.getString(1));
                    principal.putExtra("userPass", fila.getString(2));
                    BaseDeDatos.close();
                    startActivity(principal);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "La contraseña no coincide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "El usuario con correo "+usermail+" no existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Rellena todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

**Intentos para solucionarlo:**

-Usar fotos con menor tamaño (No funcionó)

-Meter las imágenes en otras partes del fragment (No funcionó)

Answer (score 0):

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference`
Parece que unos de tus EditText (`userMail`, `userPass`) es nulo.
Asegúrate de que los dos estén referenciadas a su respectivo view. Puedes usar `findViewById`, `viewBinding` o `dataBinding`.

Comment: Gracias por responder! @favs La cosa es que no veo la relación entre el NullPointerException y la imagen del fragment de la siguiente activity. Si uso el fragment sin la imagen, la app no crashea y funciona bien el getText de userMail y userPass

Answer (score 0):

AL final he cambiado el id de la imagen de "ImageViewX" a algo como "like" o "twoot",
he dejado de recibir ese error, a cambio, me da otro error al inicio de la actividad de NavigationDrawer generada automáticamente por android studio

Answer (score 0):

El problema se define aquí:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

y aquí:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

No se puede ejecutar el método llamado mediante `android:onClick` desde el layout ya que el método que intentas llamar trata de acceder a un método de un EditText que tiene valor null.

de hecho lo que tratas de realizar es incorrecto:

```
El CardView funciona perfectamente, pero cuando añado algún ImageView me salta un NullPointerException al obtener los datos de un EditText de un método de la actividad anterior
```

Si tratas de obtener información que fue cargada en un EditText que se encuentra en otra Activity no obtendrás la referencia del EditText, su valor sera null.

Si deseas pasar valores entre actividades revisa:

[Enviar texto desde EditText a un TextView de otra clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/70560/enviar-texto-desde-edittext-a-un-textview-de-otra-clase/70565#70565)