# ¿Como eliminar información de preferencias compartidas?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Tengo una aplicación en la que estoy usando prefencias compartidas para guardar los datos de acceso para utilizar una rest api desde un sync-adapter. Dichos datos los recabo desde el momento en que el usuario inicia sesión (desde el LoginActivity.java), para que luego sean utilizados por el sync-adapter (SyncAdapter.java), pero el problema viene cuando el usuario cierra su sesión y borro los datos de las preferencias compartidas con:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.clear().apply();
```

Si después vuevo a iniciar sesión con datos de usuario diferente la sección del sync-adapter continua con los mismos datos (como si no borrara los datos de las preferencias compartidas antes de cerrar sesión). Creo que puede ser porque las preferencias compartidas se guarden según el contexto de la aplicación pero me resulta un poco complicado el averiguar como eliminar ese error, de igual forma adjunto las dos secciones del código para su mejor comprensión.

### LoginActivity.java

Sección para el inicio de sesión

```
// Shared preferences
jsonObjectTemp = new JSONObject(responseString);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("TrackerTrackerGPS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("username", txt_user.getText().toString());
editor.putString("password", txt_password.getText().toString());
editor.putString("name", Constants.decodeBase64(jsonObjectTemp.getString("nombreCompleto")));
editor.putString("email", Constants.decodeBase64(jsonObjectTemp.getString("email")));
editor.putString("token", serverResponse);
Log.d("Shared", sharedPreferences.getString("username", "Null"));
Log.d("Shared", sharedPreferences.getString("password", "Null"));
editor.apply();
```

### SyncAdapter.java

Sección para consultar el API en segundo plano periódicamente

```
// Get all the id's of the fleet
JSONObject bodyMonitor = new JSONObject();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("TrackerTrackerGPS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Log.d("Shared-SYNC-U", sharedPreferences.getString("username", "Null"));
Log.d("Shared-SYNC-P", sharedPreferences.getString("password", "Null"));
String usernameDec = sharedPreferences.getString("username", "Null");
```

### DrawerMainNavigationActivity.java

Sección para el cierre de sesión

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.clear().apply();
Intent intent1 = new Intent(DrawerMainNavigationActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent1);
```

Nota: Como referencia, estoy haciendo una aplicación que muestra la trayectoria de dispositivos GPS en tiempo real, por esta razón es que estoy implementando el SyncAdapter junto con las preferencias compartidas. De igual forma cualquier consejo que me puedan proporcionar es bienvenido.

Answer (score 1):

**Cuando desees eliminar los valores de la preferencia debes realizarlo con el nombre de la preferencia ya que estas usando [getSharedPreferences()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager?hl=es#getSharedPreferences())** y no **[getDefaultSharedPreferences()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager?hl=es#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context))** que no necesita definir el nombre.

Ejemplo:

```
//SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("TrackerTrackerGPS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.clear().apply();
```

Puedes revisar esta respuesta:

[Guardar SharedPreferences asignandole una key mediante getDefaultSharedPreferences()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559/guardar-sharedpreferences-asignandole-una-key?rq=1)

Comment: Que tal @Jorgesys, de antemano muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda.
Ya intenté como mencionas en la respuesta que me comentas al final y sigue sin funcionar... ¿que otra posible solución crees que exista?

Comment: El nombre de la preferencia que agregué fue como ejemplo pero me parece que en realidad el que debes definir es "TrackerTrackerGPS" , veo que ya lo cambiaste en SyncAdapter.java @CarlosRodríguez En la sección para cierre de sesión es lo mismo debes definir el nombre del archivo de preferencias. Coméntame resultados!

Comment: Así es, lo tengo con ese nombre y aún así no se borra la preferencia. Anteriormente había pueso "TrackerTrackerGPS" porque no quería poner el nombre de la empresa, pero se me fue el rollo y por eso edité la otra sección de código que me faltaba, pero sigo sin poder hacerlo funcionar, lo curioso es que cuando destruyo la actividad manualmente se quita el error...

Comment: Por ejemplo:
1.- El usuario inicia sesión ("con el nombre de usuario: pepe") y se cargan los datos en el activity según los datos de las preferencias compartidas.
2.- Después de eso se ejecuta el sync-adapter cada 30 segundos actualizando las posiciones y usando los mismos datos de las shared preferences. (pero aquí usa el nombre de usuario: juan, que es el usuario anterior que había ingresado en la aplicación, esto a mi me indica que si se borran las preferencias cuando estoy en una actividad, pero en el sync adapter parece no tener efecto inmediato.)

Comment: 3.- Después de esto si yo cierro la aplicación desde el administrador de tareas (para destruir el activity y que lo vuelva a crear todo de nuevo) se muestra correctamente en la primera carga las posiciones de los GPS de pepe y ya no se muestran para nada los de juan, por lo que creo que hay algún pequeño detalle que me estoy perdiendo que no he podido dar con el. Espero haber sido un poco más claro en esta ocasión, y de antemano muchísimas gracias por toda la ayuda.