# SharedPreferences solo me guarda y carga un dato

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences

hola hice estos procesos para guardar y cargar con `SharedPreferences` unas ubicaciones, yo tengo 3 botones y cuando los presiono se guarda la ubicacion actual, ahora el problema es este si yo guardo la ubicacion en uno solo de los botones cierro la aplicacion y la vuelvo a abrir y guardo otro boton al cerrar y volver a abrir la aplicacion tira error. pero si en la primera ejecucion guardo las 3 ubicaciones la aplicacion funciona perfecto

este es mi codigo de guardado y de cargado

```
public void guardarpreferencias() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Gson gson2 = new Gson();
    Gson gson3 = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(loccasa);
    editor.putString("localizacionC", json);
    String json2 = gson2.toJson(loctrabajo);
    editor.putString("localizacionT", json2);
    String json3 = gson3.toJson(locfacultad);
    editor.putString("localizacionF", json3);
    editor.apply();
}

    public void cargarpreferencias(){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Gson gson2 = new Gson();
        Gson gson3 = new Gson();
        String json = preferences.getString("localizacionC",null );
        Type type = new TypeToken<Location>() {}.getType();
        loccasa = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        String json2 = preferences.getString("localizacionT", null);
        Type type2 = new TypeToken<Location>() {}.getType();
        loctrabajo = gson2.fromJson(json2, type2);
        String json3 = preferences.getString("localizacionF", null);
        Type type3 = new TypeToken<Location>() {}.getType();
        locfacultad = gson3.fromJson(json3, type3)
    }
```

lo de crear varios gson y varios type era a modo prueba

esto es lo que me sale en logcat

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke protected java.lang.ClassLoader() with no args
>
> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: Can't instantiate abstract class java.lang.ClassLoader

Comment: El problema es que estas obteniendo incorrectamente SharedPreferences, agregué respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

No estas definiendo un nombre de archivo de preferencias por lo tanto se supone que estarías usando [getDefaultSharedPreferences()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager?hl=es#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)), por lo tanto estas es la forma correcta para guardar las preferencias (es necesario el contexto si no te encuentras en una `Activity`):

```
public void guardarpreferencias(Context context) {
    //SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    //SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
      SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Gson gson2 = new Gson();
    Gson gson3 = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(loccasa);
    editor.putString("localizacionC", json);
    String json2 = gson2.toJson(loctrabajo);
    editor.putString("localizacionT", json2);
    String json3 = gson3.toJson(locfacultad);
    editor.putString("localizacionF", json3);
    editor.apply();
}
```

para obtener los datos:

```
  public void cargarpreferencias(Context context){
        //SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
         SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Gson gson2 = new Gson();
        Gson gson3 = new Gson();
        String json = preferences.getString("localizacionC",null );
        Type type = new TypeToken<Location>() {}.getType();
        loccasa = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        String json2 = preferences.getString("localizacionT", null);
        Type type2 = new TypeToken<Location>() {}.getType();
        loctrabajo = gson2.fromJson(json2, type2);
        String json3 = preferences.getString("localizacionF", null);
        Type type3 = new TypeToken<Location>() {}.getType();
        locfacultad = gson3.fromJson(json3, type3)
    }
```

También puedes usar [getSharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager?hl=es#getSharedPreferences()), Te sugiero revisar:

[Guardar SharedPreferences asignandole una key mediante getDefaultSharedPreferences()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559/guardar-sharedpreferences-asignandole-una-key-mediante-getdefaultsharedpreferenc/8564#8564)