# Pedir un valor solo una vez, guardarlo y acumularlo para usarlo siempre en java con Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, estructuras-de-datos

Buen dia,
 tengo en esta interfaz donde en el EditTex señalado en rojo es un valor que quiero dejar fijo luego que lo solicite una vez 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esa activity la envio a otra la activity2 donde tengo esta estructura.

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle !=null) {

        uni =bundle.getString("u");
    }
```

para recolectar el dato de uni, en esa misma activity tengo un metodo donde uso esa variable

```
String miunidades=uni;
int valorUnidad = Integer.parseInt(miunidades);
```

La convierto por que viene en String y luego realizo la operacion

```
if(suma == 1){
      valorUnidad=valorUnidad+0;
         }if(suma==2) {
            valorUnidad = valorUnidad + 2;
                }if(suma==3){
                     valorUnidad=valorUnidad+2;
               }
                textViewcalculo.setText("Dosis: "+valorUnidad);
```

Y ese valor no quiero que al volver a iniciar la aplicacion tenga que ingresarlo por que requiero que sea acumulativo y se guarde y tome ese nuevamente y continue la operacion.

Gracias

Comment: En el sitio puedes encontrar informacion de como guardar valores usando SharedPreferences. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559/guardar-sharedpreferences-asignandole-una-key-mediante-getdefaultsharedpreferenc?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

para guardar valores y que no se pierdan cuando se cierra la app debes usar el SharedPreferences.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como guardar un String y un int

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = myContext.getSharedPreferences(
            SHARED_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString(KEY_1, myText);
editor.putInt(KEY_2,myNumber);
editor.apply(); //Sin esto no se guarda nada
```

Y aca como haces para leer luego los datos

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
            SHARED_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String myText = sharedPref.getString(KEY_1,""); //El segundo parametro es el valor por defecto en caso de que no hayas guardado nada todavia.
int myNumber = sharedPref.getInt(KEY_2,0);
```

Como veras es similar al manejo de un Bundle, asi que no tendras problemas.

Comment: Erick, Gracias ahora me toca mirar usando mi caso si se puede implementar esa opcion o como por que no lo se usar

Comment: Intent miinten = new Intent(Calculate.this, Hitorial.class);
            d = entrada.getText().toString();
            u= unidades.getText().toString();
            miinten.putExtra("x", usuari);
            miinten.putExtra("d", d);
            miinten.putExtra("u", u);
            startActivity(miinten); 
Tengo esta manera de guardar Erick, me sirve lo que me cuentas

Comment: Julian podrias simplemente guardar el dato que necesites conservar en la SharedPreferences y despues leerlo cuando necesites tal como te puse en el ejemplo de codigo. No hay mas misterio para saber usarlo, se usa asi como te mostre en el ejemplo.

Comment: Me puedes ayudar con esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/209025/android-studio-bar-chart-graficar