# Error en SharedPreferences

Tags: android

Es mi programa quiero guardar y leer ciertos datos de configuración pero por algún motivo no se guardan o no se logra leer correctamente, alguien me podria decir cual es mi error?

Código para guardar:

```
        int mConfigBaudRate = 115200;
        int mConfigDataBit = 8;
        int mConfigBitStop = 1;
        int mConfigParity = 0;
        String mFlagConexion = "";

    public void guardarConfigSerialPortShareref(){
      SharedPreferences myPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPreferences.edit();
      editor.putInt("mconfigbaudratex", mConfigBaudRate);
      editor.putInt("mconfigdatabitx", mConfigDataBit);
      editor.putInt("mconfigbitstopx", mConfigBitStop);
      editor.putInt("mconfigparityx", mConfigParity);
      editor.putString("mFlagConexionx", "OK");
      editor.commit();
}
```

Código para leer:

```
    public void leerConfigSerialPortShareref() {
      SharedPreferences myPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
      mConfigBaudRate = myPreferences.getInt("mconfigbaudratex", 0);
      mConfigDataBit = myPreferences.getInt("mconfigdatabitx", 0);
      mConfigBitStop = myPreferences.getInt("mconfigbitstopx", 0);
      mConfigParity = myPreferences.getInt("mconfigparityx", 0);
      mFlagConexion = myPreferences.getString("mFlagConexionx", "");
}
```

Comment: Solo asegura se llame previamente el método guardarConfigSerialPortShareref() y ambos métodos se encuentren en MainActivity @W1ll

Comment: No sé si tendra algo que ver pero podrías probar a cambiar editor.commit(); por editor.apply();

Comment: Otra opción es mirar que te devuelve editor.commit(); este responde con un boolean para ver si puede hacerlo o no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asi yo guardo en SharedPreferences y lo recupero asi:

```
preferences =getSharedPreferences("Record", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String PrefAccumulated =preferences.getString("Acc","acc_defecto");
                    String PrefMissing = preferences.getString("miss","miss_defecto");
                    String PrefDone = preferences.getString("done","done_defecto");

                    String Accumulated = (String.format("%s",CumpViaje));
                    String Missing = (String.format("%s",CumpKmsG));
                    String Done = (String.format("%s",CumpKms));

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("Acc", Accumulated);
                    editor.putString("miss", Missing);
                    editor.putString("done",Done);
                    editor.commit();
```

ASi Lo recupero:

```
preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Record", MODE_PRIVATE);
       String acumulado = preferences.getString("Acc",Acumulado);
       String faltantes = preferences.getString("miss",Faltantes);
       String realizados = preferences.getString("done",Realizados);
            tvKmsAccumulated.setText(acumulado);
            tvKmsMissing.setText(faltantes);
            tvKmsDone.setText(realizados);
```

y asi yo lo elimino :

```
preferencesRecord = getSharedPreferences("Record", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editorRecord = preferencesRecord.edit()
        editorRecord.clear()
        editorRecord.commit()
```

Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Tu código es correcto, si no estas obteniendo los valores en el método `leerConfigSerialPortShareref()` la razón debe ser porque no estas guardando previamente los valores, me refiero a que no llamas el  método `guardarConfigSerialPortShareref()`, asegura que este método se llame previamente.

Te sugiero revisar:

[Guardar SharedPreferences asignandole una key mediante getDefaultSharedPreferences()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559/guardar-sharedpreferences-asignandole-una-key-mediante-getdefaultsharedpreferenc)