# Pasar parámetros utilizando SharedPreferences android java

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy tratando de guardar variables desde el login para ser utilizada en cualquier parte de mi aplicación, pero no entiendo por que me llega con valor NULL.

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando:

En el login:

```
 final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("datosUsuario", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putString("codVendedor", new String(editTextUsername));
                    editor.putString("password", new String(editTextPassword));
                    editor.putString("remember", new String(remember));
                    editor.putString("login", new String(editTextUsername));
```

Y esto en donde necesito utilizarlo:

```
        remember= new Integer(pref.getString("remember", remember)).toString();
        contrasenia= pref.getString("password", contrasenia).toString();
        login= pref.getString("login", login).toString();
        codVendedor= pref.getString("codVendedor", codVendedor).toString();
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: no veo el editor.apply(); para que se guarden los datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al estar usando [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager?hl=es#getSharedPreferences()), lo único que necesitas es guardar los valores en la Preferencia, para esto, el método a utilizar es [**commit()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()) o [**apply()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()).

Te sugiero usar `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`  ya que al usar [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager?hl=es#getSharedPreferences()) se entiende que vas a obtener la preferencia desde cualquier contexto en tu aplicación.

```
 final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("datosUsuario", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putString("codVendedor", new String(editTextUsername));
                    editor.putString("password", new String(editTextPassword));
                    editor.putString("remember", new String(remember));
                    editor.putString("login", new String(editTextUsername));

                    editor.commit();
```

Para obtener los valores:

```
 SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("datosUsuario", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

remember= new Integer(pref.getString("remember", remember)).toString();
        contrasenia= pref.getString("password", contrasenia).toString();
        login= pref.getString("login", login).toString();
        codVendedor= pref.getString("codVendedor", codVendedor).toString();
```

Revisa:

[Guardar SharedPreferences asignandole una key mediante getDefaultSharedPreferences()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559/guardar-sharedpreferences-asignandole-una-key-mediante-getdefaultsharedpreferenc/8562#8562)