# Problema al guardar datos en SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

Edit: He conseguido que me guarde los datos, pero lo que me pasa ahora es que no me guarda la portada que es una imagen, en algo estoy fallando pero no sé donde. También estoy intentando hacer un método donde me actualice el activity para que cuando no hayan datos me muestre un textview con un mensaje que diga que no hay ningún libro etc. Sé que es usando la visibilidad en los identificadores de cada Textview y botón, usando el visible y el gone, pero no consigo hacer que funcione. No he puesto el código aquí para que se vea mejor el problema principal de la portada. Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda. Dejo el código actualizado aquí abajo.

Edit2: Disculpen me equivoque de clase al poner el código.

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MiCuentaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String email = user.getEmail();
    ImageView portada;
    Button botonDevolver;
    TextView tituloCuenta, editorialCuenta, autorCuenta, paginasCuenta, IsbnCuenta, resumenCuenta;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 0;
    private ImageView mImage;
    private Uri mImageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mi_cuenta);

        tituloCuenta = findViewById(R.id.tvTituloCuenta);
        editorialCuenta = findViewById(R.id.tvEditorialCuenta);
        autorCuenta = findViewById(R.id.tvAutorCuenta);
        paginasCuenta = findViewById(R.id.tvPaginasCuenta);
        IsbnCuenta = findViewById(R.id.tvISBNCuenta);
        resumenCuenta = findViewById(R.id.tvResumenCuenta);
        portada = findViewById(R.id.ivImagenDetallesCuenta);
        botonDevolver = findViewById(R.id.btnDevolverLibro);
        mImage = findViewById(R.id.ivUsuario);
        TextView nombreUsuario = findViewById(R.id.tvNombreUsuario);
        nombreUsuario.setText(email);
        findViewById(R.id.tvNoHayDatos).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("datos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String portadaUri = pref.getString("portada", "");
        tituloCuenta.setText(pref.getString("titulo", ""));
        editorialCuenta.setText(pref.getString("editorial", ""));
        autorCuenta.setText(pref.getString("autor", ""));
        paginasCuenta.setText(pref.getString("paginas", ""));
        IsbnCuenta.setText(pref.getString("isbn", ""));
        resumenCuenta.setText(pref.getString("resumen", ""));

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String mImageUri = preferences.getString("image", null);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

        if (b != null) {
            Picasso.with(MiCuentaActivity.this).load((b.getString("IMG"))).into(portada);
            tituloCuenta.setText(b.getString("TIT"));
            editorialCuenta.setText("Editorial: " +b.getString("EDI"));
            autorCuenta.setText("Autor: " +b.getString("AUT"));
            paginasCuenta.setText("Páginas: " +(Integer.toString(b.getInt("PAG"))));
            IsbnCuenta.setText("ISBN: " +(Long.toString(b.getLong("ISB"))));
            resumenCuenta.setText(b.getString("DET"));
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("datos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("portada", String.valueOf(portadaUri));
            editor.putString("titulo",  tituloCuenta.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("editorial",  editorialCuenta.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("autor",  autorCuenta.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("paginas",  paginasCuenta.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("isbn",  IsbnCuenta.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("resumen",  resumenCuenta.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
        }

        if (mImageUri != null) {
            mImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mImageUri));
        } else {
            mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_a_photo_black_24dp);
        }

        mImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imageSelect();
            }
        });

        botonDevolver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                limpiarPrefs();
            }
        });

        updateUI();
    }

    public void imageSelect() {
        permissionsCheck();
        Intent intent;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        }
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Elige una foto"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    public void permissionsCheck() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    mImageUri=data.getData();
                    SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("image", String.valueOf(mImageUri));
                    mImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);
                    mImage.invalidate();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateUI(){
        if(tituloCuenta.getText()=="") {
            findViewById(R.id.tvTituloCuenta).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvEditorialCuenta).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvAutorCuenta).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvPaginasCuenta).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvISBNCuenta).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvResumenCuenta).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.btnDevolverLibro).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvNoHayDatos).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            findViewById(R.id.tvTituloCuenta).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvEditorialCuenta).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvAutorCuenta).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvPaginasCuenta).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvISBNCuenta).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvResumenCuenta).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.btnDevolverLibro).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvNoHayDatos).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void limpiarPrefs(){
        portada.setImageResource(0);
        tituloCuenta.setText("");
        editorialCuenta.setText("");
        autorCuenta.setText("");
        paginasCuenta.setText("");
        IsbnCuenta.setText("");
        resumenCuenta.setText("");

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("datos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.remove("datos");
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        updateUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola @Riancast el problema es que no guardas la URI de la imagen que estás eligiendo desde la galería?

Comment: Buenas Daniel, verás el problema no es la imagen, el código de la imagen es otra cosa, es para elegir una imagen de perfil y que se quede ahi aunque salga de la App, como indiqué en la pregunta, esa parte está bien. El problema es lo otro, guardar los demás datos que son los TextViews y la imagen portada que pertenece a los mismos datos y no a la imagen de perfil.

Comment: Quieres guardar es el texto que seteado en el TextView y la imagen que está en el ImageView?

Comment: Una solucion seria crear un objeto que contenga la imagen y demas datos que necesites. Y guardar ese objeto no  los diferentes campos uno por uno

Comment: Ya me guarda los datos pero no la portada que es una imagen, he actualizado el código. Gracias por responder ^^

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener los valores de los TextView y guardarlos se realiza de esta forma:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("tituloCuenta",  tituloCuenta.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("editorialCuenta",  editorialCuenta.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("autorCuenta",  autorCuenta.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("paginasCuenta",  paginasCuenta.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("IsbnCuenta",  IsbnCuenta.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("resumenCuenta",  resumenCuenta.getText().toString());

    editor.putString("urlPortadaImagen", libros.getPortada());         

    //Guarda
    editor.apply();
```

Obviamente para obtener los valores de la preferencia debes usar su llave, por ejemplo para obtener el valor del primer textview

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String valortituloCuenta = preferences.getString("tituloCuenta", null);
```

---

Al guardar un valor en preferencias debes usar `.apply()` o `.commit()` para guardar el valor:

```
             SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
             editor.putString("image", String.valueOf(mImageUri));
             //Guarda
             editor.apply();
```

revisa:

[Guarda preferencia usando SharedPreferences](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/226305/95)

Comment: Buenas Jorge, si te fijas esa parte está bien, más arriba se ve como se añade la imagen. Esa imagen es la que yo elijo de la galería para ponerla de perfil y que se guarde para cuando desloguee y vuelva a logear, eso está bien. Lo que yo quiero es guardar los otros datos, los TextViews y la imagen portada que pertenece a esos datos (portada del libro).

Comment: He actualizado el código y ya me guarda los datos, el problema ahora es que no me guarda la portada que es una imagen, algo estaré haciendo mal

Comment: Veo que editaste tu pregunta si la imagen es una url simplemente guardala como :    editor.putString("urlPortadaImagen", libros.getPortada());    y la obtienes  String urlImagen = preferences.getString("urlPortadaImagen", null);

Comment: Disculpa Jorge, al editar puse el código de la clase que no era, lo que intento es la imagen de portada que recupero desde el bundle que se me guarde también en los datos al igual que los demás datos. Sólo me falta eso. Gracias por la ayuda, se agradece mucho.

Comment: Si recuperas los datos desde el bundle, estos deben ser enviados desde otra Activity, los estas enviando desde otra Activity?

Comment: Si claro, tengo un activity donde tengo una lista de datos de firebase, los envio a ésta donde los recojo y lo que me falta es que me guarde la imagen, además acabo de darme cuenta que la otra imagen también me falla ahora, osea funciona al elegir la imagen pero tampoco se guarda.