# Compartir variable de sharedpreferences ubicada en MainActivity y una clase en android

Tags: android

Tengo una variable que se captura en el MainActivity y los guardó en un sharedpreference y la proxima vez que lanzo la app puedo usar el valor de  esta variable, pero necesito que esta misma variable también sea  leída en una clase llamada TcpClient pero esta clase no tiene constructor, alguien me puede decir como hacer esto, la variable que quiero compartir es "mconfigipaddress".

Aqui esta mi MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private TcpClient mTcpClient;

public static String SERVER_IP = "192.168.4.1";
public static String SERVER_PORT = "8888";
.
.
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
.
.
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences( mypreference,Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
if (sharedpreferences.contains( SERVER_IP )) {
    mconfigipaddress = sharedpreferences.getString( SERVER_IP, "");
}
if (sharedpreferences.contains( SERVER_PORT )) {
    mconfigport = sharedpreferences.getString( SERVER_PORT, "");
}
```

Aqui esta el codigo del TcpClient:

```
public class TcpClient {

private String  mconfigipaddress = ""; //your computer IP address
private String  mconfigport = ;
private String  mServerMessage;                        // message to send to the server
private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;    // sends message received notifications
private boolean mRun = false;                         // while this is true, the server will continue running
private PrintWriter mBufferOut;                       // used to send messages
private BufferedReader mBufferIn;                     // used to read messages from the server

private String Modelox="";
public Boolean statusWIFIX = false;

/**
 * Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
 */
public TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
    mMessageListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Sends the message entered by client to the server
 * @param message text entered by client
 */
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    if (mBufferOut != null && !mBufferOut.checkError()) {
        mBufferOut.println(message);
        mBufferOut.flush();
    }
}

interface TcpListener
{
    void onReportStatusWIFIX(boolean statusWIFIX);
}

/**
 * Close the connection and release the members
 */
public void stopClient() {

    statusWIFIX = false;
    Log.e( "DEBUG-->", "Coneccion Cerrada: "+ statusWIFIX );
    sendMessage(Constants.CLOSED_CONNECTION+": " + Modelox);                // send message that we are closing the connection
    mRun = false;
    if (mBufferOut != null) {
        mBufferOut.flush();
        mBufferOut.close();
    }
    mMessageListener = null;
    mBufferIn = null;
    mBufferOut = null;
    mServerMessage = null;
}

public void run() {
    mRun = true;
    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);      //here you must put your computer's IP address.
        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
        try {
            //sends the message to the server
            mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            //receives the message which the server sends back
            getDeviceName();
            mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            sendMessage(Constants.LOGIN_NAME+": "+ Modelox);                   // send login name

            statusWIFIX = true;
            while (mRun) {                                              //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();
                if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);   //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                }
            }
            Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
        } finally {
            socket.close();                                             //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                                                                        // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);
    }
}

public interface OnMessageReceived {                                    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    public void messageReceived(String message);                        //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
}
```

Comment: La clase si tiene constructor `TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener)` de igual forma puedes crear otro consturctor que recibar la variable que necesitas

Comment: La clase si tiene constructor `TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener)` de igual forma puedes crear otro consturctor que recibar la variable que necesitas

Comment: Como?, un ejemplo por favor

Comment: @W1ll hay informacion de esto en el sitio https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559/guardar-sharedpreferences-asignandole-una-key-mediante-getdefaultsharedpreferenc te sugiero agregar la clase TCPClient completa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer mejor manejo de las preferencias, puedes crear una clase aparte donde crees los métodos de guardar y obtener los valores que guardes en las preferencias, de esta forma se te hará mas fácil llamarlas desde donde necesites hacerlo, ejemplo:

```
public class preferencias {

private static final String PREFERENCES = "preferences";

public static void SetStringValue(Context context, String key, String save) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref  = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref .edit();
        editor.putString(key, save);
        editor.apply();
    }
}

public static String GetStringValue (Context context, String key) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref  = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPref .getString(key, null);
    }
```

Con esos dos métodos puedes guardar u obtener las preferencias, con uno guardas el `String` que desees, y con el otro obtienes el mismo, en caso de no tener nada guardado, retorna nulo. Ojo, esto es un ejemplo, no necesariamente debe ser así, pero te puede ayudar con orden al código y acceder a las mismas sin problema alguno. Luego para llamarlas de ser necesario, ya sea para guardar o para obtener seria algo como:

**Para guardar el valor:**

Desde `fragment`:

```
preferencias.SetStringValue(getContext(), "KEY-GUARDADA", stringguardado);
```

Desde `Activity`:

```
preferencias.SetStringValue(Activityname.this, "KEY-GUARDADA", stringguardado);
```

Desde `Adapter` de `RecyclerView` (Quizás sea esto lo que necesites aplicar):

```
//Declaras
private Activity activity;
//Luego lo pasas en el contexto
preferencias.SetStringValue(activity, "KEY-GUARDADA", stringguardado);
```

**Para obtener el valor:**

Desde `fragment`:

```
String stringguardado = preferencias.GetStringValue(getContext(), "KEY-GUARDADA");
```

Desde `Activity`:

```
String stringguardado = preferencias.GetStringValue(Activityname.this, "KEY-GUARDADA");
```

Desde `Adapter` de `RecyclerView` (Quizás sea esto lo que necesites aplicar):

```
//Declaras
private Activity activity;
//Luego lo pasas en el contexto
String stringguardado = preferencias.GetStringValue(activity, "KEY-GUARDADA");
```

Como mencione anteriormente, es una forma de hacerlo, de igual forma puedes aplicar la que usas.

```
//Declaras
    private Activity activity;
```

y se lo pasas como contexto cuando necesites acceder a ellas (preferencias).

Answer (score 1):

Asegura definir siempre el mismo nombre de preferencia, de esta forma puedes acceder a los mismos valores en cualquier punto de tu aplicación.

Crea los métodos:

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferenciasTCP";

public void saveValueIP(Context context, String text) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("IP", text);
    editor.commit();
}

public void saveValuePORT(Context context, String text) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("PORT", text);
    editor.commit();
}



public String getValueIP(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getString("IP", "");
}


public String getValuePORT(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getString("PORT", "");
}
```

de esta forma guardarias los valores:

```
saveValueIP(getApplicationContext(), <valor IP>);

saveValuePORT(getApplicationContext(), <valor Puerto>);
```

y de esta forma los obtendrías, asignando el valor en tus variables:

```
mconfigipaddress = getValueIP(getApplicationContext());
 mconfigport = getValuePORT(getApplicationContext());
```