# SharedPreferences: Cómo Guardar/Mostrar la opción/item seleccionado de un spinner creado en XML?

Tags: android

tengo una duda acerca del uso del SharedPreferences con los Spinner, la idea es que al seleccionar un elemento del arreglo (una matriz clásica o estática) guarde los cambios, salga de la aplicación y cuando vuelva a entrar me muestre el item que el usuario ha seleccionado. Por ejemplo

```
final Spinner spinner_xml = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

  editor.putString("ElementoSeleccionado", spinner_xml 
  .getText().toString());
```

en esta última linea de código me saltará un error debido al tipo de dato del spinner. Si me pueden ayudar con este problema les agradecería mucho!

Comment: podrias agregar el error que muestra la consola?

Comment: quieres guardar la posicion del elemento seleccionado o el valor del texto del spinner?

Comment: Lo ideal es guardar la posición (indice) del elemento seleccionado, si guardas el texto este podría estar repetido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**En este caso lo ideal es guardar el indice del elemento, no el texto ya que el texto podría repetirse en los elementos del `Spinner`.**

Puedes crear 2 métodos, uno para guardar el valor del indice del elemento mostrado en tu `Spinner`:

```
public void guardarPreference(Context context, int indice) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("indice", indice);
    editor.commit();
}
```

y otro para obtener el valor del indice:

```
public int obtenerPreference(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getInt("indice", 0); //0 sería el valor default.
}
```

---

Para guardar el valor, obten su indice mediante el método `getSelectedItemPosition()` del `Spinner` :

```
guardarPreference(getApplicationContext(), spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

al volver a tu aplicación obtén el valor del indice del valor de tu `Spinner` y asignalo para que se mueva al elemento mediante el método `setSelection()` `Spinner`:

```
  spinner.setSelection(obtenerPreference(getApplicacionContext());
```

Revisa:

[Guardar SharedPreferences asignandole una key mediante getDefaultSharedPreferences()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559/guardar-sharedpreferences-asignandole-una-key-mediante-getdefaultsharedpreferenc)