# Recuperar datos guardados en Sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

A ver si  me podéis ayudar. Tengo una Activity A principal y varias que son los niveles de un juego. Desde la A me conecto a Google Play Games y en las otras se desarrolla el juego.
En las demás actividades guardo la puntuación de esta forma:

```
 saveScore(score1);

    // show score1
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_result)).setText(getString(R.string.score) + score1);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_high_result)).setText(getString(R.string.high_score) + sp.getInt("score1", 0));
```

cada nivel guarda el mejor resultado.

Mi pregunta es como puedo llevar estos datos a la activity A, para subirlos a Google Play de esta forma.

```
// saveScore
void saveScore(int score1) {
    // save score local
    if (!sp.contains("score1") || score1 < sp.getInt("score1", 0))
        sp.edit().putInt("score1", score1).commit();



    // save score in leaderboard
    if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.connect_games) && isSigned)
        Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)).submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_level_1), score1);
}
```

Comment: No se entiende mucho tu pregunta. Si, como parece, guardas los datos en `SharedPreferences`, puedes leer esos datos allí donde los necesites y enviarlos a donde tengas que enviarlos. ¿Lo estás haciendo así? ¿Qué problema tienes?

Comment: Hablas de una cosa y publicas el código de otra. Así es realmente complicado ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Ya sea que uses SharedPreferences o DefaultSharedPreferences te sugiero instanciar simpre SharedPreferences, además este método llamalo cuando en realidad desees salvar el score:

```
public void saveScore(Context context, int score1) {
    // save score local
    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("score1", score1);
    editor.commit();

    // save score in leaderboard
    if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.connect_games) && isSigned)
    Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)).submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_level_1), score1);

}
```

Para obtener el score usa el método:

```
public String getScore(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return  preferences.getInt("score1", 0); 
}
```

Te sugiero revisar:

[Guardar SharedPreferences asignandole una key mediante getDefaultSharedPreferences()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559/guardar-sharedpreferences-asignandole-una-key-mediante-getdefaultsharedpreferenc/8564#8564)