# ¿Como actualizar textview con putExtra de un intent?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent

Quiero mostrar los datos que se registren en  los shared preferences en un textview de otra actividad,si me muestra el primero pero despues solo lo reemplaza con el siguiente que se ingrese ya intente con el .append(muy posiblente lo este utilizando incorrectamente)
Estoy utilizando android studio con java
Este es el codigo de la clase de la segunda actividad

```
public class ShowPreferences extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_preferences);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        TextView Entry;
        Entry =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Entry);
        SharedPreferences preferencias=getSharedPreferences("agenda", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferencias.edit();
        preferencias.getString("nombre","");

        editor.commit();

        Entry.append( preferencias.getAll().toString()+"\n");

    }

}
```

Y este es el metodo en la MainActivity que utilizo para enviar los extras a la segunda actividad

```
public void Mostrar(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this,ShowPreferences.class);

    intent.putExtra("nombre",n);
    intent.putExtra("telefono", t);
    intent.putExtra("email", c);

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Las variables n,t y c son las variables con los datos

Comment: Quizá SharedPreferences no sea el mejor método para hacer lo que quieres. Te remplaza el nombre porque SharedPreferences, es un conjunto de clave valor, eso significa que para la clave "nombre", solo hay un único valor, y se sobrescribirá cada que pongas uno nuevo. Podrías mandar la información como un conjunto de datos pasando un HashSet por ejemplo, en vez de enviar un string. De todos modos, es confuso el código, ¿en qué momento guardas la información en sharedpreferences? ¿Qué es lo que intentas hacer? Si ya guardas los datos con sharedpreferences, ¿por qué los envías con putextra?

Comment: Te sugiero revisar como guardar y obtener valores de preferencias: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559/guardar-sharedpreferences-asignandole-una-key-mediante-getdefaultsharedpreferenc

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tienes un pequeño malentendido, de esta forma puedes **enviar informaciòn a otra Activity mediante un Intent**, pero la informaciòn no se esta guardando en las preferencias:

```
public void Mostrar(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this,ShowPreferences.class);

    intent.putExtra("nombre",n);
    intent.putExtra("telefono", t);
    intent.putExtra("email", c);

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

para recibir los datos en tu activity destino se realizarìa de esta forma:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_preferences);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        TextView Entry;
        Entry =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Entry);
       /* SharedPreferences preferencias=getSharedPreferences("agenda", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferencias.edit();
        preferencias.getString("nombre","");
        editor.commit();*/
       
        //Recibe datos.
        Bundle parametros = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if(parametros !=null){
           String nombre = parametros.getString("nombre");  
           String telefono = parametros.getString("telefono"); 
           String email = parametros.getString("email"); 
           Entry.setText(nombre + " " + telefono + " " + email );
        } 

       

    }
```

revisa:

[¿Como enviar datos entre activities?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/como-enviar-datos-entre-activities)

---

**Si deseas usar preferencias, puedes guardar los valores en tu Activity y estos valores pueden ser leìdos en cualquier parte de la aplicaciòn.**

```
public void Mostrar(View v) {

   SharedPreferences preferencias=getSharedPreferences("agenda", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
   editor = preferencias.edit();
   editor.putString("nombre", n);
   editor.putString("telefono", t);
   editor.putString("email", c);

   //Guarda valores en preferencia.
   editor.apply();

   Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this,ShowPreferences.class);
   startActivity(intent);

}
```

En tu Activity destino puedes leer los valores de esta forma:

```
public class ShowPreferences extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_preferences);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        TextView Entry;
        Entry =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Entry);
        SharedPreferences preferencias = getSharedPreferences("agenda", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String nombre = preferencias.getString("nombre", "");
        String telefono = preferencias.getString("telefono", "");
        String email = preferencias.getString("email", "");
        Entry.setText(nombre + " " + telefono + " " + email );

    }

}
```

Revisa:

[Guardar SharedPreferences asignandole una key mediante getDefaultSharedPreferences()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559/guardar-sharedpreferences-asignandole-una-key-mediante-getdefaultsharedpreferenc)