# Como puedo guardar datos dinamicos en SharedPreferences

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences

Quisiera guardar datos en sharedpreferences de forma dinamica, es decir que el usuario pueda ingresar nombres y darles en guardar

```
SharedPreferences sharpref = getPreferences(context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharpref.edit();

    editor.putInt("id", id);
    editor.putString("nom_act", nombre_actividad);
    editor.putString("fecha_act", fecha_actual );
    //debo hora actual
    editor.putString("fecha_max", fecha_maximo);
    //debo fecha actual
    editor.putString("hora_max", hora_max);
    editor.putInt("rango", rango);
```

Me gustaria poder rescatar valores de forma dinamica, ya sea en un sharedpreferences o en un ArrayList pero de activity a fragment

Comment: a que te refieres con dinamica? ya revisaste : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559/guardar-sharedpreferences-asignandole-una-key-mediante-getdefaultsharedpreferenc?rq=1https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559/guardar-sharedpreferences-asignandole-una-key-mediante-getdefaultsharedpreferenc?rq=1

Comment: dinamica es que vaya guardando objetos a medida que el usuario presione boton "terminar registro"