# Incrementar el puntaje obtenido desde una variable

Tags: android, android-studio, variables, app, sharedpreferences

estoy trabajando en una app con android studio en el que luego de realizar un test, recupero el valor "score" obtenido y no envió al "Menú principal" de la app con `SharedPreference`, todo correcto hasta ahí, el problema es que cada ves que reinicio el test, se va sobrescribiendo ese valor y no incrementa, mi objetivo es que una vez obtenido ese valor, se sume al anterior.

Ejemplo: obtuve un "Score: 2" en el anterior test, en el siguiente obtuve "Score: 3" y que de en total "Score: 5", si me podrían dar una mano lo agradecería muchísimo!, muchas gracias de antemano!

**ACTIVITY PRINCIPAL**

```
    int sscore = 0;



    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);


        user_id = findViewById(R.id.name);
        profileImage = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        scored = findViewById(R.id.scoreee);


        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            Glide
                    .with(this)
                    .load(Objects.requireNonNull(currentUser.getPhotoUrl()).toString())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_profile_icon_free_vector)
                    .into(profileImage);
        }

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            user_id.setText(user.getDisplayName());
        } else {
            finish();
        }


        bntfacil = findViewById(R.id.facil);
        bntfacil.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent facil = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, QuizzEasyActivity.class); //llama a la activity en modo facil
            startActivity(facil);
        });
        bntnormal = findViewById(R.id.Intermedio);
        bntnormal.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent normal = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, QuizzNormalActivity.class);
            startActivity(normal);
        });
        bntdificil = findViewById(R.id.dificil);
        bntdificil.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent dificil = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, QuizzHardActivity.class);
            startActivity(dificil);
        });
        bnttimetrial = findViewById(R.id.contrarrelog);
        bnttimetrial.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent contrarreloj = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, QuizzTimeTrialActivity.class);
            startActivity(contrarreloj);
        });
        bntajustes = findViewById(R.id.ajustes);
        bntajustes.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent ajustes = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Ajustes.class); 
            startActivity(ajustes);
        });
        findViewById(R.id.logout).setOnClickListener(view -> signOut());

    }

    public void signOut(){
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences datos = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        sscore=datos.getInt("puntos", 0);
        scored.setText("Score: "+sscore);

    }
public void guardaScore(Context context, int sscore) {
    SharedPreferences datos = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    //Obtiene score guardado y lo suma con el nuevo valor.
    int scoreGuardado = datos.getInt("puntos", 0);
    sscore = sscore + scoreGuardado;

    //Guarda el nuevo valor de Score.
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = datos.edit();
    editor.putInt("puntos", sscore);
    editor.apply();
}
}
```

**ACTIVITY SECUNDARIA DE DONDE SE GUARDA EL "SCORE"**

```
public class QuizzEasyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView totaldepreguntasTextView, preguntasTextView;
    Button bntEnviar, bntInicio, bntomitir;
    int score=0;  //puntuacion de respuestas correctas
    int totalpreguntas = PreguntasRespuestasEasy.pregunta.length; 
    int preguntaactualIndex = 0;
    String seleccionarrespuesta = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quizz_easy);

        totaldepreguntasTextView = findViewById(R.id.total_preguntas);
        preguntasTextView = findViewById(R.id.preguntaTextView);
        bntInicio = findViewById(R.id.bntini);
        bntEnviar = findViewById(R.id.bntEnviar);
        bntomitir = findViewById(R.id.bntnexxxt);

        bntomitir.setOnClickListener(this);
        bntEnviar.setOnClickListener(this);

        totaldepreguntasTextView.setText("Total Questions: "+totalpreguntas); 
        bntInicio.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent inicio = new Intent(QuizzEasyActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(inicio);
        });cargarnuevapregunta();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        EditText respuesta = findViewById(R.id.edit);          
        String r1 = respuesta.getText().toString();           

        respuesta.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                bntEnviar.setEnabled(s.toString().length() > 0);
            }
        });



        Button clickedButton = (Button) view;
        if (clickedButton.getId()==R.id.bntEnviar){
            if (r1.equals(PreguntasRespuestasEasy.respuestacorrecta[preguntaactualIndex])){   
                score++;
            }
            respuesta.setText("");
            preguntaactualIndex++;   
            cargarnuevapregunta();
        }else {
            seleccionarrespuesta = clickedButton.getText().toString();
            clickedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);                             
        }if (clickedButton.getId()==R.id.bntnexxxt){
            respuesta.setText("");
            preguntaactualIndex++;               
            cargarnuevapregunta();
        }
    }
    void cargarnuevapregunta(){
        if(preguntaactualIndex == totalpreguntas ){
            finishquizz();
            return;                                      
        }
        preguntasTextView.setText(PreguntasRespuestasEasy.pregunta[preguntaactualIndex]);
    }
    void finishquizz(){
        String passStatus = "";
        if(score > totalpreguntas*0.80){ 
            passStatus = "APROBADO";
        }else {
            passStatus = "REPROBADO";
        }
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(passStatus)
                .setMessage("Su puntacion es "+ score +" de "+totalpreguntas)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La obtención del valor guardado en la preferencia es correcto:

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences datos = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    sscore=datos.getInt("puntos", 0);
    scored.setText("Score: "+sscore);
}
```

**El problema debe encontrarse al obtener el valor y guardarlo, aquí debes obtener el valor guardado, sumarlo con el nuevo valor y guardarlo nuevamente.**

Para guardar el nuevo valor de `sscore` en la preferencia, te sugiero usar el siguiente método:

```
public void guardaScore(Context context, int sscore) {
    SharedPreferences datos = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    //Obtiene score guardado y lo suma con el nuevo valor.
    int scoreGuardado = datos.getInt("puntos", 0);
    sscore = sscore + scoreGuardado;

    //Guarda el nuevo valor de Score.
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = datos.edit();
    editor.putInt("puntos", sscore);
    editor.apply();
}
```

---

Actualización:

En la Activity secundaria no tienes un mecanismo para guardar el score en la preferencia, debes agregar en esta Activity el método sugerido, y puedes guardar la preferencia cuando muestras el diálogo final:

```
 void finishquizz(){
        String passStatus = "";
        if(score > totalpreguntas*0.80){ 
            passStatus = "APROBADO";
        }else {
            passStatus = "REPROBADO";
        }
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(passStatus)
                .setMessage("Su puntacion es "+ score +" de "+totalpreguntas)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .show();
      
        //* Realiza guardado del score.
        guardaScore(this, score);

    }
```

---

Para usar preferencias, revisa:

**[Guardar SharedPreferences asignandole una key mediante getDefaultSharedPreferences()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559/guardar-sharedpreferences-asignandole-una-key-mediante-getdefaultsharedpreferenc)**

Comment: editor = settings.edit() es una variable local que tendria que crear?, mas en concreto, el "settings"

Comment: @Zen perdón, ya corregí , debe ser:  editor = datos.edit();

Comment: Tengo un problema, no sabría como declarar ese código en mi actividad

Comment: Básicamente pongo ese metodo tal cual en la actividad principal (actividad que subí en la pregunta) pero no funciona

Comment: @Zen agrega la Activity a tu pregunta-

Comment: ya edite la pregunta para mostrar ambas activitys

Comment: El problema es  que en realidad no estas guardando el valor de "score", agregué actualización.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono perfectamentemente, ahora puedo continuar con el proyecto, realmente agradecido por tu contribucion

Comment: ¡Excelente @Zen Saludos!