# sharepreference java android

Tags: java, android

Hola amigos buenas noches, espero se encuentren excelente, les quería pedir ayuda, necesito recibir datos (sharepreference) de una actividad principal a otra actividad en Android y no se como recibir los datos para mostrar en un textView, si me pudieran ayudar es para una tarea, se los agradecería un montón, hasta ahora puedo enviar los datos pero sin sharepreference, muestro el código.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText eTTtnom, eTTtape;
private Button  btningresar;
private Button  btnGuardar;
private ProgressBar progressBar1;
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("guardar", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btningresar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIngresar);

    eTTtnom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTTtnom);
    eTTtape = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTTtape);
    progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);


    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast") FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.btnIngresar);
    btningresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            utilitario.setDefaultsPreference("usuario","usuario",view.getContext());

            /*  new task1().execute(eTTtnom.getText().toString()); */
        }
    });


}

class task1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btningresar.setEnabled(false);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strings[0];
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        progressBar1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btningresar.setEnabled(true);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ResultadoActivity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("usuario",s);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

}
```

}

segunda activity

public class ResultadoActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextView Tvresultado;
private TextView Tvchiste;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_resultado2);

    Tvresultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TvCredenciales);
    String nombreUsuario = getIntent().getStringExtra("usuario");
    Tvresultado.setText("Bienvenido:" + nombreUsuario);
}

/*  hasta aca codigo bueno    */

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si deseas enviar información de una `Activity` a otra, se puede realizar de esta forma:
**[Enviar datos entre Activities](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/36924/95)**

Al usar `SharedPreferences` en realidad no se "envia" información, lo que se realiza es guardar la información y esta puede ser leída en algún otro punto de tu aplicación, por ejemplo. otra `Activity` o `Fragment`.

[**Guardar y obtener un valor mediante getSharedPreferences()**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8564/95)

---

Si deseas usar preferencias, primeramente te sugiero crear dos métodos, uno para guardar el valor en la preferencia:

```
public void guardaValor(Context context, String text) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_jongusar", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("usuario", text);
    editor.commit();
}
```

y otro para obtener el valor que se tenga guardado en la preferencia.

```
public String obtieneValor(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_jongusar", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getString("usuario", "");
}
```

Entonces puedes guardar el valor, al obtenerlo en `onPostExecute()` de tu `AsyncTask`:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        progressBar1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btningresar.setEnabled(true);

        //*Guarda valor en preferencia.
        guardaValor(MainActivity.this, s); 
      
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ResultadoActivity2.class);
        //intent.putExtra("usuario",s); // Ya no es necesario envíar el valor.
        startActivity(intent);

        
    }
```

y al cargar `ResultadoActivity2` puedes recuperarlo:

```
public class ResultadoActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView Tvresultado;
private TextView Tvchiste;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_resultado2);

    Tvresultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TvCredenciales);
 
    //*Obtiene valor guardado en preferencia.
    String nombreUsuario = obtieneValor(this);//getIntent().getStringExtra("usuario");
    Tvresultado.setText("Bienvenido:" + nombreUsuario);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @Jorgesys,  me ayudaste mucho, ya que soy nuevo en esto y estoy estudiando y todo esto es a contra tiempo, espero te encuentres excelente