# ¿Cómo declarar una variable global y poder usarla desde cualquier activity en mi app?

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite, crud

Estoy practicando crear una app con java y 3 tablas sin relacionarse en SQLite(Cliente, Proveedor y Producto), ya cree el CRUD en las primeras 2, en la 3era. Al agregar un nuevo producto ingreso nombre, precio y hay un EditText que se rellena con el valor de una variable global que declaré y es igual a 0.

Se guarda el registro en la BD y lo muestra en un RecyclerView, pero al dar tap sobre el debería abrirse otro Activity para editar con los campos anteriores ya rellenados pero sucede que se cierra.

Adjunto parte del código.

**Creación de la tabla**

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLA_PRODUCTOS + "(" +
            "id_producto INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "nombre TEXT NOT NULL," +
            "precio_venta REAL NOT NULL," +
            "stock_inicial INTEGER NOT NULL)");
```

**Clase Producto**

```
private long id_producto;
private String nombre;
private double precio_venta;
private Integer stock_inicial;
```

**Controlador Producto**

```
public int editarProducto(Producto productoEditado){
    SQLiteDatabase baseDeDatos = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues valoresParaActualizar = new ContentValues();
    valoresParaActualizar.put("nombre", productoEditado.getNombre());
    valoresParaActualizar.put("precio_venta", productoEditado.getPrecio_venta());
    valoresParaActualizar.put("stock_inicial", productoEditado.getStock_inicial());
    String campoParaActualizar = "id_producto = ?";
    String[] argumentosParaActualizar = {String.valueOf(productoEditado.getId_producto())};
    return baseDeDatos.update(NOMBRE_TABLA, valoresParaActualizar, campoParaActualizar, argumentosParaActualizar);
}
```

**Así declare la variable en NuevoProductoActivity y la asigné al EditText**

```
public static final String stock_inicial = "0";
```

---

```
etStockInicialProducto.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
etStockInicialProducto.setText(stock_inicial);
```

**Al dar click sobre el registro en el Activity Producto**

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            Producto productoSeleccionado = listaDeProductos.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(ProductoActivity.this, EditarProductoActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id_producto", productoSeleccionado.getId_producto());
            intent.putExtra("nombre", productoSeleccionado.getNombre());
            intent.putExtra("precio_venta", productoSeleccionado.getPrecio_venta());
            intent.putExtra("stock_inicial", productoSeleccionado.getStock_inicial());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }));
```

**En el Activity Editar mando a llamar la variable**

```
import static com.rdmm91.migestion.NuevoProductoActivity.stock_inicial;
String nuevoProductoStock = stock_inicial;

long idProducto = extras.getLong("id_producto");
    String nombreProducto = extras.getString("nombre");
    double precio_ventaProducto = extras.getDouble("precio_venta");
    Integer stock_inicialProducto = extras.getInt("stock_inicial");
    producto = new Producto(idProducto, nombreProducto, precio_ventaProducto, stock_inicialProducto);

etEditarNombreProducto.setText(producto.getNombre());
    etEditarPrecioProducto.setText((int) producto.getPrecio_venta());
    etEditarStockInicialProducto.setText(nuevoProductoStock);
```

Soy bastante novato en esto quizás ubiqué mal la variable o la declaré mal, realmente no sé, espero puedan orientarme un poco para seguir aprendiendo y mejorando. Perdón por tanto código.

Comment: Lo más común es pasar información entre actividades. Tal vez puedas utilizar una variable estática como otra forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Si declaras una variable como `public` y `static`, en teoría puedes leer su valor desde cualquier otra clase, pero el problema principal es que los actuales sistemas operativos al requerir memoria lo primero que eliminan son precisamente las variables con modificador `static`, por lo tanto, esto no es una práctica recomendada.

Lo recomendable es enviar datos entre Activities: [¿Cómo enviar datos entre activities?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/c%C3%B3mo-enviar-datos-entre-activities)

O también guardar el valor en una preferencia para que este valor pueda ser leído desde cualquier clase en tu proyecto:
[Guardar SharedPreferences asignandole una key mediante getDefaultSharedPreferences()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559/guardar-sharedpreferences-asignandole-una-key-mediante-getdefaultsharedpreferenc?noredirect=1&lq=1)